# Tomcat redirect problem with url pattern with sub folder

Tags: apache, tomcat, redirect, proxypass

I have a tomcat application with a number of servlets. Each of the general servlets checks whether the application has been setup and if not it does a redirect to contextpath/admin/setup.

This works fine when accessing the tomcat instance directly but when its behind apache using proxy pass the redirect goes to /contextpath/contextpath/admin/setup

this is my apache config

```
ProxyPass /mbeclectic/ http://localhost:9098/mbeclectic/
 
       ProxyPassReverse /
       ProxyHTMLEnable On
       ProxyHTMLURLMap http://localhost:9098/mbeclectic/ /mbeclectic/
       ProxyHTMLURLMap / /mbeclectic/
```

Ive tried redirecting using the complete external url but the same result.

I can access /contextpath/admin/setup directly from a browser.

I suspect its an error in the apache config, any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I changed the redirect url "admin/setup" ie without the contextpath. This works directly and via apache.